# Detect '@' (arobase) on key press via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

Seems like a dumb question at first, but I'm struggling to find a way to correctly find that the user has entered the '**@**' value in a field.

The issue is mainly because of the keyboard layouts, like between Mac's and Windows.

For example, in my current layout, to display the '**@**', I have to `altgr + 0` but I believe for mac's, it's the first key at the top left of the keyboard.

So my question is rather simple, how can you trigger the condition when the user enters '**@**', independant from the OS/keyboard layout/Brand ?

I searched on Google to find some libraries/snippet that would work, and the only few I found was not plateform independant and did not worked with mine.

Comment: How about checking on the `keypress` event?

Comment: @MaxArt: I'm pretty sure the OP figured that much out already.

Comment: I tried with keyup, not keypress ... and that's kid, is how I missed the answer! ;)

Comment: (Keypress is good, with a bit of `String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);`)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#theinput').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var isArobase = /@/.test($(event.target).val());
});
```

then if your want to test for email:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
  return re.test(email);
}
$('#theinput').on('keyup', function(event) {
  var isArobase = validateEmail($(event.target).value());
}
```